# Increment Loop to a excel cells horizontally PHP

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel

I am working in a reporting module using Laravel 5 and http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel and my question is how to I populate a data in excel horizontally? Because, vertically it's pretty easy let's say I want to populate vertically is cell `A1` onwards so I can go with

```
for($x=1;$x=<5000;$x++)
{
  $sheet->cell('A'.$x, 'Some Value');
}
```

But what about horizontally? Let's say I will begin in `A1` onwards on a loop? How do I that? Coz excel has the formatting of cell location like `AA, BBB, ABC` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PHPs Perl-style character incrementing

```
for($x='A'; $x != 'IW'; $x++)
{
  $sheet->cell($x . '1', 'Some Value');
}
```

Note that you can't use a `<` comparison for the termination, because the comparison will be alphabetic and `AA` is alphabetically less than `B`; so you use a `!=` comparison instead with a column address one higher than the last you want to access.... the above will finish after cell `IV`

Comment: Thanks! But my question is how will the loop know when to stop? For example I have 10 records to horizontally loop in. Sometimes it's 1000. It depends on the number of records. Its that possbile? Coz I'm going to stop with IV then I will have a limit?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question..... how does your vertical loop know when to stop? Because you've populated cells for rows `1` to `5000`..... this is no different, you've populated cells for columns `A` to `IV`.... you know how many records you have..... use the underlying PHPExcel library functions like `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()` to work out what column address that corresponds to

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I only need to populate colmuns which horizontally. I could your suggested code but the way I need to stop is using alphabet which is 'IW' in your example. Problem is if I have let's say 1000 records I dunno what alphabet is equivalent of that. I've tried @Andrius solution below and works for me. Coz that will increament columns depending on the number I put in which is the numeber of records.

Comment: the PHPExcel method `getHighestDataColumn()` will return a string of the last column that has data in it.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca - if you have 1000 records, then you use a call to `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(1000)` to get the column address for the 1000th column.... but be warned that BIFF format xls files only support a max of 256 columns

Comment: @MarkBaker I see. Didn't know that. Tried it and it worked. Thank you so much for the reminder. I'll keep that in mind. Selected this as answer for it is a better approach.

Comment: @MarkBaker I got this Laravel Excel method [stringFromColumnIndex] does not exist does it mean that the plugin I'm using doesn't have that function?

Comment: [laravel-excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) is a wrapper around the [PHPExcel library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/) and the `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex` method is part of PHPExcel, not a part of laravel-excel.... that's why I referred to it as "underlying"